# Indent all words selected with the tab command with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I use the tkinter text in Python if I select a block of words with the mouse and press the tab command, only the first word will be indented. Is there a way to have all the selected words indented?

Comment: provide a [mre] and explain the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to get the selection index and insert `\t` in each line.

here is an example

```py
import tkinter as tk


def tab(event):
    
    try:
        start_line = int(text.index("sel.first")[0])
        last_line = int(text.index("sel.last")[0])
        
        for x in range(start_line, last_line+1):
            text.insert(f"{x}.0", "\t")

        return 'break'

    except tk.TclError:
        pass

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
text.bind("<Tab>", tab)

root.mainloop()
```

`text.index("sel.first")` returns the index of the first selection and the `text.index("sel.last")` returns the index of the last selection.